# How to update cell value in UWP Microsoft Toolkit DataGrid?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-community-toolkit

i am trying to update the cell value from the datagrid
but i dont know how to set the new celll value

```
    private async void GridViewAccount_CellEditEnded(object sender, 
    Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGridCellEditEndedEventArgs e)
    {
       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection((App.Current as App).Connectionstring))
       {
           SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_updateaccount", con);
           command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", accountId);
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", null); //how to get the new cell value
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", null); //how to get the new cell value
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", null); //how to get the new cell value
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", null); //how to get the new cell value
           await con.OpenAsync();
           await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
           con.Close();
           accountToolRefresh();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to achieve a **two-way** binding. As follows:

Xaml code:

```
<controls:DataGrid     
      x:Name="MyDataGrid" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      CellEditEnded="MyDataGrid_CellEditEnded"                                    
      ItemsSource="{x:Bind Users,Mode=TwoWay}">
         <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
           <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="AccountId " Binding="{Binding Id,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
           <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="UserName" Binding="{Binding UserName,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
           <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Password" Binding="{Binding Password,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
         </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<User> Users;
public MainPage()
{      
   this.InitializeComponent();
   Users=new ObservableCollection<User>
   {
      new User(){Id=1, UserName=”tom”, password=”123”},
      new User(){Id=2, UserName=”lily”, password=”563”}   
   }
           
 }     
       
public class User:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int _id;
        public string _username;
        public string _password;
      
        public int Id 
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set {
                _id = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return _username; }
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("UserName");
            }
        }
        public string PassWord
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("PassWord");
            }
        }
        
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyname = null) 
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
```

When you change the cell value, the `Users` collection will be updated. Then in `CellEditEnded` event, you could get the `DataContext` of the current row and convert it to an object, so that you could get its properties via this object.

```
 private async void MyDataGrid_CellEditEnded(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndedEventArgs e)
{        
  User user=e.Row.DataContext as User;  
  …… 
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", user.accountId);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.username);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", user.password);     
}
```

Comment: thank you very much my problem solved
,now i just need the input validation of datagrid
thanks again